# Unrecognized character escape in elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, escaping

Been trying to do regex search in elasticsearch, with the following query:

```
{
"query": {
  "constant_score": {
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "regexp": {
              "displayName" : "(^a\w+| a(\w+))"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

This regex works fine in https://regex101.com/ but the above query gives :

```
nested: QueryParsingException[[bm_md_acct_9993342_v1] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized character escape 'w' (code 119)\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 10, column: 37]]; }
```

I tried escaping it in different ways but with no success. How do I properly put the escape sequence?

Tried :

```
{
"query": {
  "constant_score": {
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "regexp": {
              "displayName" : "(^J\\w+| J(\\w+))"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

gives empty result even though a record of displayName "Jason Cremer" exists.

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: If you want to only match entries that start with  `J` and then have 1+ letters with spaces, use `"J[a-zA-Z ]+"`

Comment: Or, if you want to match when either the first name or the last name starts with `J`, use `"J[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+ J[a-zA-Z]+"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The query string must have a word that contains 'J'

Comment: Ok, try just `".*J.*"`. Or `[^J]*J.*` - either will find an entry with `J` inside. You may add `[a-zA-Z]`: `".*J[a-zA-Z].*"` if you want to make sure there is a letter after `J`.

Comment: I think the `".*J[a-zA-Z].*"` pattern is closest to what you are trying to achieve, does it work as expected?

Comment: Ok, I will post an answer to explain what is going wrong with your regex and what you may try.

Answer (score 4):

Regexp query in elasticsearch is not fully flexible.
For example `\w` matches any word character in normal regex convention, but in elasticsearch you can not represent `\w` since `\` is a reserved character in elasticsearch.

To make `\w` valid in elasticsearch, we have to escape using `\` which will convert your regex to `\\\w`. Now this `\\\w` alters the meaning of your regex.

It will match `"\" followed by "w" rather than matching word character`.

My suggestion is replace \w in your regex with [a-zA-Z0-9_]. This will work. 
And also you can not use `^` for a single character. Remove that in your regex and your query would be

```
 { "query": {   "constant_score": {
     "filter": {
       "bool": {
         "must": [
           {
             "regexp": {
               "displayName" : "(J[a-zA-Z0-9_]+| J([a-zA-Z0-9_]+))"
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     }   } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Acc. to the [Elasticsearch regex documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html), its syntax does not support shorthand character classes so common in other regex flavors, so you can't use `\w`, you can only use character classes (or bracket expressions) like `[a-zA-Z]` to match letters, or `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` to match what `\w` matches in JavaScript.

Next, `^` and `$`, also common in other flavors, are not supported by ES regex. The whole pattern is *anchored by default*, thus these are not even necessary.

Now, you want any word having `J` inside. There are several options:

1. `".*J.*"` will match any string that contains `J`
2. `".*J[a-zA-Z].*"` will match any string that  contains `J` and then a letter
3. `"J[a-zA-Z].*|.* J[a-zA-Z].*"` will match any string that  starts with `J` and then a letter, and then any characters, or any string that contains a space, `J`, and any letter after it.